# Tell is not a member of actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class MyActor1[T<: Actor: ClassTag] extends Actor {
  //....
}

import akka.actor.{Props, Actor}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class MyActor2[T <: Actor: ClassTag] extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Start =>
      val actor1 = context actorOf Props[MyActor3]      //MyActor3 is another actor
      actor1 ! Get

    case Result(ids: List[Int]) =>
      val myActor1List = ids map { new MyActor1[T](_) }   
      myActor1List foreach { _ ! SomeMessage } // error: "!" is not a member of MyActor1[T] 
  }
}
```

The error is `"!" is not a member of MyActor1[T]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `!` is a member of `ActorRef`, not `Actor`. You should always access actors via `ActorRef`s, not via instances of your classes that extend `Actor` directly.

Your `myActor1List` contains instances of class `MyActor1`, instead of `ActorRef`s. Create your actors by calling `context.actorOf[MyActor1]` instead of instantiating `MyActor1` objects directly.

You're already doing it in your own code. Notice the difference between:

```
// Create an actor and get an ActorRef
val actor1 = context actorOf Props[MyActor3]

// Create instances of your actor class directly
val myActor1List = ids map { new MyActor1[T](_) }
```

Comment: `val myActor1List = ids map { context actorOf Props[MyActor3] }` ? What about `T`?

Comment: Note, you can pass the `id` (that's what you're mapping over) by using a `Props`, something like this: `ids map { context actorOf Props(classOf[MyActor3], _) }`. Don't know about `T`. Why is it a problem?

Comment: the problem is that I have to create `new MyActor1[T](_) ` and not just `new MyActor1(_)`

Comment: Use `ids map { id => context actorOf Props(new MyActor1[T](id)) }` then. `Props` allows you to supply factory block for your actor objects.